# I don't understand why this code is not working properly

Tags: c, string

In C programme:
Question is: You are given a binary string S of size N. Now you need to tell total how many 01 and 10 pair exist in the given string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {

    int i,t,j,count;
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char s[n];
    scanf("%s",&s[n]);
    j=0,count=0;
        while(s[j]!='\0')
        {
           if(s[j]=='1' && s[j+1]=='0')
           {  count++;}
            else if(s[j]=='0' && s[j+1]=='1')
            { count++;}
            j++;
        }
        printf("%d\n",count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When n is less than 6,there is showing correct answer. But when n is greater then 6, this is showing 0. Please help me out.

Comment: Your array is too short. Need extra byte for 0 terminator. Use `char s[n+1];`

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s",&s[n]);` - that `&s[n]` is the address where `s` **ends**. It's the first address **after** `s`. You want to write to the first address of `s`: `&s[0]` or just `s`.